# What is the best way to pass Class reference as a method parameter?

Tags: kotlin

I am really new to Kotlin. I want to implement something like this:

```
class classA {
fun doSomething(f: class){
when (f){
classB -> print("class B")
classC -> print("class C")
}
}
```

I don't have any idea on how to proceed. Should I use generics? Or anything else? Feel free to mark as duplicate if answer is already present.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, and why are you trying to do it this way?  You're effectively trying to reinvent polymorphism; you might find it works better if you can make your `f` an enum or implement some interface with a method than you can then call.  That way you'd get better compile-time type-safety, reduce inter-class dependencies, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can write

```
fun doSomething(f: KClass<*>) {
    when (f){
        B::class -> print("class B")
        C::class -> print("class C")
    }
}
```

and then call it as `doSomething(B::class)` or `doSomething(String::class)`.

Many libraries will use `Class` instead of `KClass`, in which case you need `B::class.java`.

See [Class References](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#class-references) documentation.